# Update html file using Jsoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I want to update HTML file using java code, I am able to read attribute using Jsoup but I want to update attribute value and save the same to HTML file

I have tried Jsoup
element  `tag.attr(attrname, value)`

Same is not doing anything with my HTML file

Comment: Can you post a code snippet?

Comment: Jsoup is meant for parsing, not modifying HTML files. It can do this and what you're trying to do should work but don't count on Jsoup if you want to keep formatting, inline scripts and HTML comments untouched.

Answer (score 2):

You can just read the html file using `java.nio`, parse and modify it with Jsoup and save it to a file again using `java.nio`:

```
Path input = Path.of("input.html");
Document document = Jsoup.parse(Files.readString(input), "UTF-8");
document.select("#my-id").attr("class", "test");
Path output = Path.of("output.html");
Files.writeString(output, document.outerHtml());
```

For example if the input file looks like this:

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Foo</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="my-id">Bar</div>
 </body>
</html>
```

The output file will be modified like this:

```html
<html>
 <head> 
  <title>Foo</title> 
 </head> 
 <body> 
  <div id="my-id" class="test">Bar</div>  
 </body>
</html>
```

But remember that the whitespaces of the output file could be different from the input file.