# Replace text in HTML element and update the same file with Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I have been trying for a while to edit the text within an element, but I've not had much luck finding similar examples.  Those that I have found haven't worked.

The code I have at the moment is pretty much the same as shown in the Jsoup [docs](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/modifying-data/set-text)

**Java**

```
public void updateTitle() {
        Element content = doc.body().getElementById("titleCER");
        System.out.println(content); // Prints '<p class="certificate-CcM" id="titleCER">CERTIFICATE</p>'
        content.text().replaceAll("text", "Change to this"); // does nothing
        content.text("change to this!"); // does nothing
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<p class="certificate-CcM" id="titleCER">CERTIFICATE</p>
```

Right now when the code runs, it finds the element by ID fine, but then doesn't update anything in the HTML file

Thank you for any help

Comment: Turns out it is changing the text in the 'doc' variable, not the HTML file.  I will need to find a way to save the doc to a HTML file.

I will add an answer when I've sorted it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update html file using Jsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57140073/update-html-file-using-jsoup)

Comment: @JanezKuhar By the looks of it yes that would work, I answered my question on this post because I found a very similar solution

Answer (score 0):

I was never writing the edited Document back to the HTML file

The solution is:

```
public void updateTitle() throws IOException {
        Element content = doc.body().getElementById("titleCER");
        System.out.println(content);
        content.text("change to this!");
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(input,"UTF-8");
        writer.write(doc.html() ) ;
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    }
```

where 'input' is:

```
File input = new File("/origionalFile.html");
```

Answer (score 0):

Jsoup's text() method is used for retrieving the text content of an element, but to modify the text, you should use the text(String text) method.

```
public void updateTitle() {
        Element content = doc.body().getElementById("titleCER");
        if (content != null) {
            // Update text content using the text(String text) method
            content.text("Change to this!");
            System.out.println(content); // Prints the updated element
        } else {
            System.out.println("Element not found");
        }
    }
```

Comment: This only modifies the DOM in memory. The OPs answers is the correct one.